# What is the difference between HTTP_USER_AGENT and HTTP_X_USER_AGENT?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I sometimes see one or the other in my server logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTTP headers beginning with `X` are officious headers. They are not specified in the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), but just coined by some 3rd party as kind of vendor-specific or "de facto" standard and taken over by many others, like HTTP [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) in case of proxy servers.

The particular HTTP `X-User-Agent` header is often inserted by some independent messenger between the actual client and the server, like a proxy, loadbalancer, transcoder, etc, but also some XMLHttpRequest based libraries. It often identifies the messenger itself. The `User-Agent` header should still represent the actual client. You also see this header sometimes in emails, this then represents the email program/software responsible for sending the mail.

That it is called `HTTP_X_USER_AGENT` (uppercased, `HTTP` prefix, underscores instead of hyphens) is PHP specific.